# Multipart File Exceed Limit Exception

Tags: spring, file, multipart

Im using SPring boot to develop my system, but i got this exception when uploading a file that exceed 1MB ( using multipart file type ) . Can anyone explain it to me ? thank you

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Multipart Mime part file exceeds max filesize
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.MultiPartInputStreamParser$MultiPart.write(MultiPartInputStreamParser.java:111) ~[jetty-util-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.MultiPartInputStreamParser.parse(MultiPartInputStreamParser.java:681) ~[jetty-util-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.MultiPartInputStreamParser.getParts(MultiPartInputStreamParser.java:400) ~[jetty-util-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.getParts(Request.java:2146) ~[jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.extractMultipartParameters(Request.java:386) ~[jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.extractContentParameters(Request.java:309) ~[jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.extractParameters(Request.java:257) ~[jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.getParameter(Request.java:826) ~[jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
>   at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:70) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
>   at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
>   at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:103) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
>   at vn.com.splussoftware.sms.config.OAuth2AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(OAuth2AuthenticationFilter.java:71) ~[bin/:na]
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585) [jetty-servlet-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143) [jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577) [jetty-security-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223) [jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127) [jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515) [jetty-servlet-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185) [jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061) [jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141) [jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97) [jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499) [jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:311) [jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257) [jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:544) [jetty-io-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635) [jetty-util-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555) [jetty-util-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_66]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Configure file uploads in `application.properties` file. Set limit for a single multi part file and for the overall request (can contain multiple files) to 3 MB (Spring Boot 2.x):

```
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size: 3MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size: 3MB
```

The defaults are:

```
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size: 1MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size: 10MB
```

Reference: [Spring Boot: Handling Multipart File Uploads](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-multipart-file-upload-configuration)

Comment: thank you sir, it solve my problem straight and forward but can i config it as unlimited ? Like -1 (Yeah -1 is unlimited, i tried )

Comment: For others coming here from Google, latest documentation states the only property needed is: `spring.http.multipart.max-file-size`.

Comment: It seems that these properties has moved around a bit. This is what's working for me:

`spring.http.multipart.maxFileSize: 20MB
spring.http.multipart.maxRequestSize: 20MB`

Comment: Its important to note here `spring.http.multipart.maxFileSize` and `spring.http.multipart.maxRequestSize` is for springBoot 1.X where `spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size` and `spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size` is for springBoot 2.X

Answer (score 6):

Things has changed a bit in the propery file.

```
spring:
  http:
    multipart:
      maxFileSize: 20MB
      maxRequestSize: 20MB
```

See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.4.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/MultipartProperties.java for a list of all properties that can be configured.

Comment: One may also want to define `file-size-threshold: 5MB` otherwise the whole file gets loaded into memory.

Answer (score 2):

For Spring Boot 2 the `application.yml` file will be like this:

```
spring:
  servlet:
    multipart:
      enabled: true
      max-file-size: 20MB
      max-request-size: 20MB
```

Answer (score 1):

in  node 
`<servlet>  .... <multipart-config>
            <location>/tmp</location>
            <max-file-size>1000000000</max-file-size>
            <max-request-size>1500000000</max-request-size>
            <file-size-threshold>0</file-size-threshold>
        </multipart-config>`

Comment: For reasons unknown, my spring-boot application ignores this setting when deployed on jetty. Only application.properties settings work properly.

Comment: you use  @MultipartConfig in your servlet ?

Comment: an exemple for upload with spring and jetty : https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/

Comment: And in that example the max size is specified in .properties file.

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation of the spring (https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/) recommends to put in `src/main/resources/application.properties`:

```
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=100Mb
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=100Mb
```

is what worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

To add no limit to file size and request size

Spring Boot 1.5.x:

```
spring.http.multipart.max-file-size=-1
spring.http.multipart.max-request-size=-1
```

Spring Boot 2.0.x:

```
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=-1
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=-1
```